# Selecting rows per ID using a hierarchy of phrases in a different column in R

Tags: r, filter, datatable, subset

I have a table:

```
ID     Gene     Tier     Consequence   
1314   ABC      TIER1    missense  
1314   PKD1     TIER1    frameshift  
6245   BJD      TIER1    splice_site_variant 
1314   ADAMST   TIER3    stop_gain
7631   PKD2     TIER1    missense
7631   BFH      TIER2    stop_gain
5336   PKD1     TIER3    missense
1399   PKD1     TIER2    non-coding
1399   TMEM     TIER3    missense
```

Per person I would like to output rows with the highest tier value (with TIER1 > TIER2 >TIER3). I could turn the TIERs into numbers but at some point I would also have to do the same thing with the consequence column also (stop_gain > frameshift > etc.) so was wondering if there was a method in R without transforming the data. Ideally a base R solution as I work in an airlocked HPC with external tools annoying to import.

Desired output would be:

```
ID     Gene     Tier     Consequence   
1314   ABC      TIER1    missense  
1314   PKD1     TIER1    frameshift  
6245   BJD      TIER1    splice_site_variant 
7631   PKD2     TIER1    missense
5336   PKD1     TIER3    missense
1399   PKD1     TIER2    non-coding
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try `subset` + `ave` like below

```
subset(df,as.logical(ave(Tier,ID,FUN = function(x) x == min(x))))
```

giving

```
    ID Gene  Tier         Consequence
1 1314  ABC TIER1            missense
2 1314 PKD1 TIER1          frameshift
3 6245  BJD TIER1 splice_site_variant
5 7631 PKD2 TIER1            missense
7 5336 PKD1 TIER3            missense
8 1399 PKD1 TIER2          non-coding
```

Comment: thank Thomas that worked well. If one wanted to say output one row per ID with frameshift being higher in the hierarchy than missense (i.e so ID 1314 would output the PKD1 gene row over the ABC gene row) how would one do that?

Comment: Maybe `subset(df[order(df$Tier,df$Consequence),],as.logical(ave(Tier,ID,FUN = function(x) seq_along(x)==1)))`